# What is the best way of creating a label in Cocos2D that will change its text constantly?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I know that changing the text of a CCLabel is really time consuming and hence cannot be done every frame. So how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that the general recommendation when you have to update a level regularly (for a score or the like) is to use a CCLablBMFont.  CCLabelBMFont uses a bitmap font file, so it will only draw to the screen once and then can just replace the numbers or letters as needed.  You really shouldn't be using CCLabelTTF for anything but completely static text, so CCLabelBMFont would be the way to go for you.

*Edit

Before you worry about the images you need to make sure you uncomment these lines in your AppDelagate:

```
//if( ! [director enableRetinaDisplay:YES] )
    //CCLOG(@"Retina Display Not supported");
```

Then when you create your .fnt and .png make sure to create a second .fnt and .png, which is twice is big as the original font you created and append -hd after the name.  So your files should look like "original.fnt" "original.png" "original-hd.fnt" "original-hd.png"

Comment: Does CCLabelBMFont support retina display? How can I use it to support it?

Comment: @NachoSoto Yea it supports it, my understanding is you would just save a font file that is 2x as big as the original.fnt as original-hd.fnt and then it should be good to go.

Comment: As well as the textures? same filename format? That wasn't working for me :/

Answer (score 1):

It's not all *that* bad. If you have one label and you really need to change it every frame, I would go ahead and try it. You might not notice any problem. If you do notice a slowdown, though, you can either (a) use a CCLabelAtlas, which is much faster, or (b) set up a counter that tracks how many frames have passed since the last time you updated it, so you're only doing it every 2 or 3 or 5 frames.